# Firestore Rule function to check role OR company

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to implement role based authorization in my app before we launch for production. I have a function that checks whether the user is accessing data from only their company. I need to also make sure that a user with the role "SuperUser", "Tester", or "Manager" can also access the data even though they aren't part of the company. I've looked at other role based implementations but they don't seem to address this scenario of having to check either the company or the role.

I have the rule that has the OR statement here:

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company)/users/$(request.auth.uid)) 
|| hasRole(['SuperUser', 'Manager', 'Tester']);
```

And I have this as the function for hasRoles:

```
function hasRole(roles) {
    return get("/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/Seva Development/users/$(request.auth.uid)").data.roles.hasAny(roles);
}
```

When I add this function the user is denied access, even when the left side of the OR statement is true. I can only assume something is wrong with the function, but I've been unable to find where from firebase documentation.

The document I'm trying to access looks like this:

[image: firebase console database]

How can I modify this function to allow me to check if the user is part of our organization and has one of the specified roles?

This works if you have the role but aren't part of the company:

```
allow read: if isUserCompany(company) 
                        || hasRole(['SuperUser', 'Manager', 'Tester']);
```

But it will fail if you are part of the company and don't have the role. What I can't figure out, is that this works if you are part of the company but don't have the role:

```
allow read: if isUserCompany(company)
```

So the left side works, the right side works. But they don't work together.

It also works if I write:

```
allow read: if isUserCompany(company) || false;
```

Which makes me assume the problem must be with the hasRole function if the role doesn't exist. I tried writing a function to check for the role first, but it still failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the contents of the document that's referenced by get().

Comment: Are the rules both functioning independly? In other words does it work if you only have the left rule or only the right rule?

Comment: @AndréKool The left rule (checking company) functions independently. The right rule (checking roles) does not. Which is why I question the role lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a string to get() instead of a path.  Note the [reference documentation for `get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) says the argument is a [`Path`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path).  According to the docs for Path:

> Paths can be created in two ways. The first is in the "raw" form
>   beginning with a forward slash /:
>
> /path/to/resource
>
> The second is by converting from a string using the path() function:
>
> path("path/to/resource")

If you want to compose a string to become a path (because you have a space in there somewhere), you'll have to use the path() function.  Or, you can use the [`bind()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path#bind) function to insert the values that have spaces in them.  Using path():

```
function hasRole(roles) {
    return get(path("databases/" + database + "/documents/companies/Seva Development/users/" + request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny(roles);
}
```

Note that the leading slash is missing from the string form of the path, and all variables need to be added by concatenation.

Or you can just remove the space from "Seva Development" and just use the raw form of the path.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the space even with binding or using the path formula, but after removing the space, it seems to be working on the simulator, which is huge progress but denies permission when I run it from my local machine... Is there something I'm missing? It has been 30 min. since the simulator said it worked and I've tried reloading the page, etc.

Comment: This answer helped me a ton, life saver! Don't know why I couldn't find the path function before. Thanks!

Comment: @tempSeva What do you mean by "run it on my local machine"?

Comment: when I run ng-serve for the angular environment. It seems that the problem wasn't as much the "local machine" as it was that that the left side (checking the user company) no longer works. For example, if you have one of the roles, it will give access, but if you are part of the company, it will not longer give access. I have no idea why that is...

Comment: If I remove the part about the roles, it will give access if you are part of the company. If I don't, or if I only have the part about the roles, it will give access if you have the role, but not if you are only part of the company.